# out-of-core SVD in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to run the python (numpy) code:

```
numpy.linalg.svd(M.dot(M.T))
```

but M is a dense float64 matrix of shape 100224 x 349800

Obviously, it does not fit in memory.

I know pytables is supposed to be able to do out-of-core operations
but I have only found examples of element-wise operations, nothing like
a dot product or SVD.

Is this even possible in python? and if not, what are my options?
(Any programming language is probably fine)

Comment: The number of FLOPS would be bad enough (O(mn^2) where m>n, m and n being the dimensions of the matrix) but moving large chunks of the matrix back and forth from disk to memory would be very time-consuming. If it was actually necessary to do the SVD on this size of matrix, you might have to borrow at least a small supercomputer that has >200Gb of RAM available. If you could explain your wider problem a bit more, perhaps there might be ways to solve it without doing this enormous SVD?

Comment: please also note that computing the SVD of `M.dot(M.T)` makes no sense! `M.dot(M.T)` is symmetric positive-(semi)definite with 'eigenvalues == singular values'. If you need the eigs of  `M.dot(M.T)` you just have to remember that they are the squared singular values of `M` itself.

Comment: This is something that is done.  I do not understand why stack overflow users so confidently bash things.